# How to add child to Firebase database with key that increments with every child added?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I believe the correct way to do this without having any duplicates is to use a transaction, however for some reason the MutableData object passed in the function does not return any children, despite the fact that I added some dummy data to the Firebase database for testing. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Cheers!

Here is the relevant code:

Database:

```
games/
    0/
        ...
    1/
        ...
```

Transaction:

```
private void startNewGame(DatabaseReference _DatabaseRef) {
    _DatabaseRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            Log.v("CUSTOMDEBUG", Long.toString(mutableData.getChildrenCount()));
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }
    });
}
```

For some reason, the above code logs 0 as the child count, despite the fact that I have added 2 children with the keys "0" and "1". The REALLY weird part is, is if I try to explicitly get a child, it works!

```
mutableData.child("1");
```

actually returns the correct child with all the data!

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to explain. What are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the documentation for [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions). Especially the note at the end of the section:

> Note: Because doTransaction() is called multiple times, it must be
>   able to handle null data. Even if there is existing data in your
>   remote database, it may not be locally cached when the transaction
>   function is run, resulting in null for the initial value.

Your transaction handler is receiving a null first.  You need to detect the case and deal with it by returning a successful transaction indication.  If there is really data at the location, it will get called a second time with that data, and possibly more times if there are conflicts with other clients writing there.

Returning null from your Transaction handler is likely aborting the transaction so that it's not getting called again.  Instead return a [success indicator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Transaction.html#success(com.google.firebase.database.MutableData)) with the same data you originally received.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I completely misunderstood how transactions work, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
databaseReference.child("JsonArrayNode").setValue(value1);
databaseReference.child("JsonArrayNode").setValue(value2);
.....
databaseReference.child("JsonArrayNode").setValue(valueN);
```

Firebase, by default, assigns 0, 1, 2, ... , N index for value1, value2, ... valueN. It means key automatically increment.

If multiple devices are writing the same JsonArrayNode at the same time, then data can be corrupted by concurrent transactions. In this case only, you call `transactions`, because on Transaction you have callback `onComplete()`, which gives you knowledge on whether transaction has been successful or not? If not, you repeat modification again.